# MySQL INSERT causes MySqlException on .ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am able to connect to the database fine, but when I try to INSERT I get this cryptic error:

Error 0 has occurred: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

I've checked and all of my params have values and they match the column titles exactly except for ID which is auto increment.

Where am I going wrong, please?

```
Dim iReturn As Boolean

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    Dim strConnection = "server=" & txtServer.Text & ";" _
                & "user id=" & txtUsername.Text & ";" _
                & "password=" & txtPassword.Text & ";" _
                & "database=" & txtDatabase.Text

    conn.ConnectionString = strConnection

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO twc_data VALUES(@todaysdate,@fname,@mname,@lname,@address,@city,@state,@zip,@email,@arPhone(0),@arPhone(1),@arPhone(2),@arCategory(0),@arCategory(1),@arJob1(1),@arJob1(2),@arJob1(3),@arJob1(4),@arJob1(5),@arJob2(1),@arJob2(2),@arJob2(3),@arJob2(4),@arJob2(5),@arJob3(1),@arJob3(2),@arJob3(3),@arJob3(4),@arJob3(5),@arCategory(2),@arCategory(3),@arCategory(4),@arCategory(5),@arCategory(6),@arCategory(7),@arCategory(8),@arCategory(9),@arCategory(10),@pdfilename,@strText)"

        cmd.Prepare()

        With cmd
            .Prepare()
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@todaysdate", param(0))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", param(1))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", param(2))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", param(3))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", param(4))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", param(5))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", param(6))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", param(7))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", param(8))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arPhone(0)", param(9))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arPhone(1)", param(10))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arPhone(2)", param(11))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(0)", param(12))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(1)", param(13))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob1(1)", param(14))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob1(2)", param(15))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob1(3)", param(16))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob1(4)", param(17))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob1(5)", param(18))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob2(1)", param(19))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob2(2)", param(20))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob2(3)", param(21))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob2(4)", param(22))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob2(5)", param(23))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob3(1)", param(24))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob3(2)", param(25))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob3(3)", param(26))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob3(4)", param(27))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arJob3(5)", param(28))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(2)", param(29))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(3)", param(30))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(4)", param(31))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(5)", param(32))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(6)", param(33))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(7)", param(34))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(8)", param(35))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(9)", param(36))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arCategory(10)", param(37))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdfilename", param(38))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@strText)", param(39))
        End With

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        iReturn = True
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        param(40) = "Error " & ex.Number & " has occurred: " & ex.Message
        logError()
        iReturn = False
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

    Return iReturn
```

Comment: copy the SQL code to a string and try to execute it directly on the my sql server

Comment: Is there really *no* other information about the exception?  You seem to be throwing away potentially useful information, such as a stack trace or any potential inner exceptions or any other properties on the `MySqlException`.  Don't throw away information about errors.

Comment: Are parentheses permitted in parameter names?  Even if they are, are *unmatched* parentheses permitted?  (See parameter 39)  Try without all those parentheses, maybe those are syntax errors to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the column names of the table with out ID.

```
INSERT INTO twc_data([column names of the table]) VALUES(@todaysdate,.....
```